# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'okres' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method

Tags: python, html, post, python-requests, python-requests-html

When I want to post request with python requests library, I get this error :

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'okres' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult Get(Int32)' in 'Vulcan.Efeb.Uczen.Web.Controllers.Api.Oceny.OcenyController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

my request code:

```py
getGrades = Session.post('https://some_website_i_want_to_send_post_request',
                         headers=headers,
                         data={'okres': '41618'},
                         allow_redirects=True)
```

I tried changing data from `{'okres': '41618'}` to `{'okres': 41618}` and removing allow_redirects, but it didn't work.

Comment: '41618' is string, but the server is expecting an integer. use 41618 without the quotes

Comment: This created another problem :

Comment: ```{"success":false,"feedback":{"Handled":false,"FType":"Error","Message":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'okres' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult Get(Int32)' in 'Vulcan.Efeb.Uczen.Web.Controllers.Api.Oceny.OcenyController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.\r\nParameter name: parameters","ExceptionType":null,"ExceptionMessage":"","InnerExceptionMessage":"","Action":null,"data":null,"success":false,"requestId":null}}```

Comment: @LiquidDeath "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'okres' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult Get(Int32)' in 'Vulcan.Efeb.Uczen.Web.Controllers.Api.Oceny.OcenyController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.\r\nParameter name: parameters",

Comment: i put {'okres': 41618} instead {'okres': '41618'} @LiquidDeath

Comment: is it possible to share the url ?

Comment: yes, https://uonetplus-uczen.resman.pl/rzeszow/01lo/Oceny.mvc/Get

Comment: unforunately you cant access it with loging in

Comment: alright. i dont see any issues here with the code, it might be the data issue, try the same operation in postman, if it works, you will get the python code in postman. also let me know if it succeeds

Comment: I guess I won't be able to do that in postman as I would have to move all the code to postman. @LiquidDeath

Comment: And I have to send like 10 requests to get required headers for this request

Comment: you dont have to do 10 requests. just fill in the headers you already got

Comment: I mean I would have to be in a same session to get a those headers

Comment: @LiquidDeath ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎ ‎

Comment: i couldn't find anything wrong with the data passed. if i were you, i would have checked in postman to know if my code is wrong or issue with the backend service

Comment: So I guess it will be hard to solve my problem as it works fine when I open it in my browser. And when I run with the code giving all the headers, data forms etc. I need, I still get this error

Comment: have you tried in postman ?

Comment: Yes, and it gave the same result

Comment: Check for the python code in postman. It will work

Comment: Will it work If I added other modules that I need to install with pip?

Comment: Like i added Beautiful soup and js2py

Comment: I think there is a problem because of missing data in prameters or request body

Comment: @LiquidDeath ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎